# Chapter number of paragraphs in a word document

Tags: c#

How we can read chapter number of paragraphs in word document using Open XML?

Suppose ,
1. Heading 1
   1.1 Heading 2
are 2 paragraphs in a word document, 
how we can read values 1, 1.1 etc.

Comment: how are reading the rest please specify some code

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you want.

```
public List<string> getChapterNumbers()
    {
        List<string> chapters = new List<string>();

        foreach (Word.Paragraph p in currentDocument.Paragraphs)
        { 
            string style = p.get_Style();

            if (style.Equals("Heading 1"))
            {
                var chapter = p.Range.ListFormat.ListString;
                chapters.Add(chapter);
            }

            if (style.Equals("Heading 2"))
            {
                var chapter = p.Range.ListFormat.ListString;
                chapters.Add(chapter);
            }
        }

        return chapters;
    }
```